# Converting expressions with template literals

Tags: javascript, expression, console.log, template-literals

When I use the `console.log()` method with a template literal and I interpolate the expression **5 + 5** within `${}`, the result is not given in the console.

This is my code:

```
 <script>
      console.log('five plus five is ${5 + 5}');
 </script>
```

When I check the console, it just repeats, "five plus five is `${5 + 5}`" without the quotes, of course.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks! (=

Comment: `'` is not `\``. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong "quotes" ... use the back-tick  **`**

```js
console.log(`five plus five is ${5 + 5}`)
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! Dumb mistake on my part. =p

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it inside back tick (`) character not inside single(`'`) or double quotes `"`, See [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
console.log(`five plus five is ${5 + 5}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use template literals with backticks.

> Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes.

```js
console.log(`five plus five is ${5 + 5}`);
```

[Learn more about Template Literals at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)